# If possible, how can I use a Chrome Extension to edit the code in a <script> tag before execution?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a page with an element as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var foo = new Bar();
    });
</script>
```

(the $() function is the JQuery $(document).ready() alias.
I'm looking to have my Chrome Extension modify this, to either set foo to global, or otherwise modify foo (e.g. perform foo.x = 2, foo.y = 10), but I'm struggling to find any way to do this, I've tried changing the element, copying every script on the page including this one, editing this one, then attempting to rerun all the scripts, and a few more, but I'm finding nothing. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come to is faking jQuery... Although this method is very much limited and not scalable whatsoever, it is still better than nothing, so...

You would need to:

1. Prevent jQuery to be loaded at first
2. Create the `$()` that remembers the functions it needs to pass to jQuery later
3. Somehow recognize the function with `foo` and remove it from array from point 2.
4. Get `document.body.innerHTML` and find your function
5. Inject this function into the array
6. Finally let jQuery act and pass the functions from point 2 to the jQuery

Comment: Any tips on preventing the function defining $() from loading? And I can't yet find a way to run any code with my extension before the page scripts are run?